# Restrict deselecting remaining records when we select selected record in Checkbox model

Tags: javascript, extjs

In checkbox model multi select at some point when we have multiple selections, If we select already selected row all the remaining selections are getting deselecting expect that selected row. I just want to restrict that. check this fiddle.[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tgh)

Comment: I am not getting the question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selection model's mode to simple. It still allows multiple selections, but retains the existing selections when you click the row. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tjo

```
selModel: {
    selType: 'checkboxmodel', 
    mode: 'SIMPLE'
},
```